# What is the default value of React.PropTypes.func

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

What's the correct value to replace the question marks with and why?

```
RecentProjectsSection.propTypes = {
  onClose: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  projects: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

RecentProjectsSection.defaultProps = {
  onClose: ?????
  projects: [],
};
```

Comment: Empty, noop function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need a function, what it does - up to you.

```
RecentProjectsSection.defaultProps = {
  onClose: () => { 
    // your logic here...

    return;
  }
  projects: [],
};
```

Comment: It won't let me yet